# Duplicating a new line in a new command

Tags: macros, arguments

I'm trying to write a new command which will duplicate the last line. I don't want the content duplicated. I just want the template for the last line line duplicated so I can enter new data to the new line..

```
\newcommand{\cvproject}[4]{%
  {\large\color{emphasis}#1\par}
  \smallskip\normalsize
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2} \hspace{2em}{\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}#3}\par
  \smallskip}
  \medskip
}
```

The above command works without a problem and gives an last line output similar to 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     {calendar icon} 2012

What I want to achieve is this

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     {calendar icon} 2012

BBBbbbbbbbbbbbBBBBBBBBBBBB      {calendar icon} 2013

ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc     {calendar icon} 2013

The command I have written for this purpose is this :

```
\newcommand{\cvleader}[5]{%
 {\large\color{emphasis}#1\par}
 \smallskip\normalsize
 \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{}{
 \textbf{\color{accent}#2} \hspace{2em}{\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}#3}\par
 \smallskip}%
 \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{}{
 \textbf{\color{accent}#4} \hspace{2em}{\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}#5}\par
 \smallskip}
 \medskip
}
```

But it give me the following error

./main.tex:207:
Runaway argument?
{\color {accent}
Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
 
                   \par 
l.207

How can I edit my new command to fix this issue?? Thanks!!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  For instance what is the `accent` color?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "I want the last line duplicated". Can you elaborate?

Comment: The argument of `\text..`-commands like `\textbf` may not contain paragraph-breaks. Thus in case argument `#2` and/or argument `#4` of `\cvleader` (those arguments go into `\textbf`) contain(s) the token `\par`--LaTeX does insert this token also when encountering in the input an empty line/two consecutive linebreaks--, or contain(s) something that in turn at some stage of expansion yields a paragraph-break, you will get the observed error-message. Instead of `\textbf{...` you can probably try `{\bfseries\selectfont...` .

Comment: There might be other issues: 1. Do you at the end really wish both a `\smallskip` and a `\bigskip`?   2. The code of `\cvleader`'s definition has lines that end with opening/closing braces. LaTeX will at the time of reading and tokenizing your .tex-input-file place space-tokens behind the brace-tokens that come from the braces in the code of your .tex-input. These space-tokens in turn may yield visible space/horizontal glue in the .pdf-output. For avoiding that, make sure such lines do not end with an opening/closing brace but with a comment-char `%` placed right behind the brace in question.

Comment: \tikzmark can give you width of the last line or any point within the last line, but it won't tell you how many characters were used.

Comment: \vsplit can separate the last line of a paragraph, but you can't use \unvbox as input to xstring.

Comment: I don't recommend to use complex macros for a CV. You will spend more time to customise and amend the commands you define to make your life easier, than to keep it simple.